# I want to create a 2d list with its rows and columns taken as input and its elements being the product of row and column numbers

Tags: python, list, matrix, input, rows

this is the code I have written but I cant figure out a way to change the values in the list to product of row number and column number

```
r = int(input("Input number of rows: "))
c = int(input("Input number of columns: "))
multi_list = [[1 for col in range(1, c+1)] for row in range(1, r+1)]

for row in range(1, r):
    for col in range(1,r):
        multi_list[row][col] = r*c

for inner_list in multi_list:
    for val in inner_list:
        print(val, end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first loop must be corrected to this:

```
for row in range(1, r+1):
    for col in range(1,c+1):
        multi_list[row-1][col-1] = row*col
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here,

1. list comprehension.
2. for loop.

the list comprehension solution:

```py
row = int(input("Input number of rows: "))
col = int(input("Input number of columns: "))
#        [[        COL                   ]       ROW                 ]
matrix = [[r*c for c in range(1, col + 1)] for r in range(1, row + 1)]
```

let's assume 2 rows and 5 columns
**1**. list comprehension:

```py
from pprint import pprint
row, col = 2, 5
matrix = [[r*c for c in range(1, col + 1)] for r in range(1, row + 1)]
pprint(matrix, indent=4, width=25)
[   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```

**2**. the other option is for loop:

```py
from pprint import pprint
row, col = 2, 5

matrix = []
for r in range(1, row + 1):
    m.append([])  # add new row
    for c in range(1, col + 1):
        m[c-1].append(r*c)
        # m[-1].append(r*c)  # this will work too.

pprint(matrix, indent=4, width=25)
[   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```